# Can I Transfer a Copy of Pokemon Omega Ruby Which Came With the 2DS Bundle?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I saw that Nintendo has recently dropped the price of the 2DS down to £79.99, including either Pokemon Omega Ruby or Alpha Sapphire, and I'm thinking of buying it. However, I would like to experience the game in 3D, so I'm just wondering if it would be possible to transfer this copy onto my 3DS, using the in-built system transfer. I've heard somewhere that you can, and other places that you can't, and I would really like a definitive answer!

Also would it be possible to transfer it to a different NNID?

This would probably also work with all other pre-installed games.

Also can I log onto both systems with the same NNID, at the same time?

Comment: Couldn't you just buy the game by itself instead of buying the 2DS with it?

Comment: No, the whole point of getting this is for the 2DS. I already have the game, in physical form, but this is a really cheap way to get a 2DS + a download copy of the game, which will be really useful, if I can transfer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I tried this out myself. I bought the 2DS with Omega Ruby and tried to do a system transfer over. The pre-installed game was in fact transferred so I can confirm that it does work.

You can transfer it to another NNID, although some of the original data on that system might be deleted. It should merge though.

I also tried to log onto both systems with the same NNID, and it turns out you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the digital copy of the game will be linked into your 3ds (or 2ds) account, if you login with your account on the 2ds and link the digital game to the account, you will be able to download the game on the other console (with the same account).

http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/227/~/how-to-transfer-content-between-nintendo-3ds,-nintendo-3ds-xl,-and-nintendo-2ds

Comment: So does this mean I can have two of the same game on different consoles?

Comment: No, the console delete all when the account is transferred to another console. (And once you transfer the account to another console, you have to wait a week to do it again, security reasons).